# toString() kind of implementation in C++14

Tags: c++

```
    class Fruit
{
private:
    std::string m_name;
    std::string m_color;

public:
    Fruit(std::string name, std::string color)
        : m_name(name), m_color(color)
    {
    }

    std::string getName() const { return m_name; }
    std::string getColor() const { return m_color; }

};

class Apple : public Fruit
{
private:
    double m_fiber;

public:
    Apple(std::string name, std::string color, double fiber)
        :Fruit(name, color), m_fiber(fiber)
    {
    }

    double getFiber() const { return m_fiber; }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Apple &a)
    {
        out << "Apple (" << a.getName() << ", " << a.getColor() << ", " << a.getFiber() << ")\n";
        return out;
    }
};
```

My question is regarding the friend function with the overloaded operator '<<'. 
I need to understand some basics which are troubling me, for one why does the function return a reference to a stream ?

Answer (score 1):

The returned lvalue ref to the stream means that you can reuse the returned value as an lvalue which references the returned object so you can chain multiple insertion operations together. For example,

```
std::cout << Apple("foo", "red", 3.4) << Apple("bar", "red", 5.5);

or perhaps better seen in terms of precedence as

(std::cout << Apple("foo", "red", 3.4)) << Apple("bar", "red", 5.5);
```

as opposed to, if you didn't return an lvalue ref, and perhaps just returned void, only the following would work:

```
std::cout << Apple("foo", "red", 3.4)
```

If you just returned `std::ostream` instead of `std::ostream&`, then an attempt to *copy* of the stream object would be attempted, and fail at compilation b.c. the copy ctor is deleted as shown here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/ostream/.

Comment: ostreams can't be copied...

Comment: ah, true. Edited to point that out based on here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/ostream/